# Settings DNS records with Hosting company or Registrar

Tags: hosting, dns, registrar

This has always got me.

I change the nameservers with the registrar and then have the option to set up the other DNS records (a ,cname, mx) with EITHER the registrar or hosting company.

Which is best? Why do you have the choice? I normally use just the hosting company and set them there.

Comment: Can someone decide where this goes and move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most flexible solution (in my opinion) is to host your DNS settings on neutral ground. this way you stay in control 100%.

this means:

- set the nameserver(s) to where you host your DNS records (the "neutral" ground)
- where you host your DNS records: configure your DNS records as you like

Answer (score 3):

It depends on:

- the features your hosting company give to you
- the features you may get elsewhere
- the features you **need**

What features does your domain name need ?

Full disclaimer: I develop https://entrydns.net/ in my free time with a sysadmin friend, a free DNS management service

Comment: Just need the standard cname,a,txt,etc settings. I can set these all up fine I just wondered which option is best.

Comment: Usually paid services offer extra features like Anycast, DNSSEC - maybe if you need those. Some large websites need really fast resolving.

Answer (score 2):

Stick with your registrar UNLESS:

- You are a sadist and wish to run your own bind servers.
- You need to have reverse PTR records setup (not likely unless you use your own mail servers, which you shouldn't by the way.  Use Google Apps or Postmark)
- You are running an application which requires load balancing or some sort of special DNS service like round robin.  (Not likely, put pound or apache in front of it)
- You need a lower TTL (time-to-live) on your records then the registrar service provides.
- You make frequent updates for numerous subdomains/records and need a powerful/faster tool then the registrar's.

I find that most registrar's have a slightly less than acceptable DNS management tool.  However, that grating experience only happens once or twice a year, most times.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend changing the dns in the domain control panel i mean with the registrar. If you want to link your domain with a hosting accounts then you have update whether the nameservers or A/MX records in the domain control panel.

if you are puchasing hosting account with two different providers for example say one is for email and the other for files. In this case, you need to update the nameservers for a hosting and A/MX records for another. So if you add these records using your registrar it will be a one step solution instead adding with the hosting.